# Inter Process Communication between Silverlight OOB & Non-Silverlight Desktop Application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

I have a `Silverlight OOB` Application installed, and I want to `send messages` to this application from any `non-silverlight desktop application` (Let this application be any `WinForms`, or `Console` Application). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking over this old thread, you can create a duplex wcf service using http polling. Call the service from any application, the silverlight client can be registered as a callback and then receive messages directly from the server.

More reading:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645027(v=vs.95).aspx